# При какой операции (компиляция, интерпретация) используются Стек и Куча?

Tags: java, стек, heap

Когда данные виды памяти задействованы? При компиляции или же при работе JVM? Сам считаю, что непосредственно в процессе интерпретации, но наткнулся на определение перегрузки метода:

> Перегрузка метода является примером времени компиляции / статического полиморфизма, поскольку привязка метода между вызовом метода и определением метода происходит **во время компиляции** и зависит от ссылки на класс (**ссылка создается во время компиляции и отправляется в стек**).

Прошу объяснить. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Общие сведения о управление памятью -> [click_me](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-memory-management) [and_me](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20Java&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Стэк - это область памяти, выделяемая для работы отдельно взятого потока, т.к. в рамках стека хранится информация о stack frame'ах этого потока. [Stack Frame](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/recursion-jvm-stacks-stack-frames/) - это, можно сказать, сущность, отвечающая за хранение информации (значения/ссылки в heap в локалных переменных, operand stack и frame data) об этапе исполнения кода (команде в рамках метода) этим методом.
Поэтому стек не может относиться на этапе компиляции, он относится непосредственно к runtime, т.е. времени исполнения программы определенным потоком.

Comment: В качестве лаконичного ликбеза также могу предложить пробежаться по [этой презентации](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qFeCN3If1W2r0cBiokoywt0JkkolPxEs/view?usp=sharing), начиная с 14 слайда.